# Shannel error: a fatal alert was received at the remote endpoint. Code 20

Tags: security, malware, remote-control, spyware, surveillance

I recently learned that I've had a cyberstalker for a year. I'm not tech savvy enough for this.

I found this error message today in my event logs: a fatal alert was received at the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 20.

There is A LOT that I don't understand. I'm just starting with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: TLS protocol error:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/schannel-error-state-960-tls-fatal-error-code-20/ba-p/722663#:~:text=The%20root%20cause%20of%20this,web%20server%20and%20load%20balancer.&text=If%20there%20is%20a%20conflict,fatal%20error%20code%20is%2020.   The root cause of this issue is that the different or incompatible chiper suites used in web server and load balancer.    What make you think this is a stalker?

Comment: Thank you, John for your answer and for your question. The volume of information I've gathered continues to grow, but the following should help illustrate why I believe this is a stalking situation - I'm very open to any alternative conclusions, as well:

Comment: @john, i tried to answer this twice. both times lost it somehow. hundreds of deleted photos, accessed my icloud account, altered contact info, knew private things that occurred when i was alone at home, threatened me never to mess with him, strange phone behavior, slow typing, strange calls, hundreds of repeat calls/attempted visits, followed me in his car, never left anything behind, made me stay upstairs for a few minutes before joining me, every single time, very paranoid, secretive, controlling, obsessive.